# How to implement soa concept in asp.net web api project?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, soa, asp.net-core-webapi

I know some basic concepts about SOA. But I don't know how I can develop a project based on SOA. So, I want to know a way for implementing SOA in Asp.NET Web API project.

Comment: SOA is not specific to any one technology. You can use ASP .Net. It relies on web services / APIs / microservices and the idea that each component delivers a specific function and comes with a well-defined contract / interface

Answer (score 1):

SOA is not a technology but a style of design/Architecture. There are different implementations of this. They are as follows.

```
Web services based on WSDL and SOAP
Messaging, e.g., with ActiveMQ, JMS, RabbitMQ
RESTful HTTP, with Representational state transfer (REST) constituting its own constraints-based architectural style
OPC-UA
WCF (Microsoft's implementation of Web services, forming a part of WCF)
Apache Thrift
SORCER
```

ASP.Net Core supports [REST api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-2.1) and if you looking at implementing SOAP based service using asp.net core here is a handy link for [this](https://stackify.com/soap-net-core/)

https://stackify.com/soap-net-core/

There are many videos on youtube and there are many websites to learn REST services. If you are familiar with c# and asp.net, you can start learn ASP.NET Core to build your restful services.

Here is a link to one video [links](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aIkpVzqLuhA).

Comment: you said nice point.thank you.but im  looking a way to understand soa concepts deeply and implement it with Restful http.can you tell me such way?